# How to check the username with database users in Laravel using Query Builder?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

Suppose I have two or more users in database in 'users' table.

```
$result = DB::table('users')->get();

if($result->username == $request->input('username') && $result->password == $request->input('password')){
            echo "Success";
        }
        else{
             echo "wrong username or password";
        }
```

This shows error as there is no username in $result. To access username. We must provide index i.e, $result[0].

How to perform this operation?

Comment: Getting password from users collection ????? why ? What's the necessity ? could you please explain that in detail more please ? because resolving the errors is one thing and experimenting on given features by reading password from your query builder is .... are you looking for "Laravel 8 Login authentication system " ??

Comment: This function is used for login. $result returns data in array. If someone wants to login then what will be the query in the if() ?

Answer (score 0):

$result is going to retrieve a collection of models, that way you must loop through this and search for the provided username in request. But, if the idea is look for a specific username value in table column, you can do

```
$result = DB::table('users')->where('username',$request->input('username'))->get();
if(count($result)) {
   //....
}
else
   echo "Not found";
```

Comment: no i want to login by username and password. All i want to compare the username and password entered by user to database username and password.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for clearning out your problem.

```
    $isAuthroized = Auth::attempt([
                                    'username'    => $request->get('username'),
                                    'password'    => $request->get('password')
                                ]);
    if($isAuthroized === true){
        return redirect()->route('your_redirect_route_name');       
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with([
        'message'   => 'Invalid User Credentials.'
    ]);
```

I hope this resolves your problem. Thank you.
Please refer [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#specifying-additional-conditions) documentation it will help more

Comment: Auth is the database name but table name is not mentioned.

Comment: Thank you Vipertecpro for your time. My problem is solved and i have posted the answer. It was a simple answer.

Comment: `Auth is the database name`.....That's fine and it doesn't matter `but table name is not mentioned.` Auth by default takes users table as default to check for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This solution solved my problem.

```
$username = $request->input('username');
    $result = DB::table('users')->where('username',$username)->get();
    if($result[0]->username == $request->input('username') && $result[0]->password == $request->input('password')){
        echo "Login Successfull";
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid username and password";
    }
```

Comment: But why would you use it like that ? have you seen that approach somewhere else ? If yes please do refer me. or if this is the way you wanted to do that's great then, i am glade you resolve that issue.

Comment: you can use first() as well you don't have to use `$result[0]` simply this `$result->username`  if you want to get single record.

Comment: 1- No i did'n see anywhere. It came onto my mind after seeing Prospero's answers here below. He used where() mehtod. 
2- Yes We can use first(), but when there are many users in the database then first() can't solve our problem. So, we will compare the username by using where() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` method of query builder.

```
$userExists = DB::table('users')->where('username', '=', $request->input('username'))->exists();

  if ($userExists) {
     echo "Success";
  } else {
   echo "wrong username or password";
}
```

Comment: Yes this is also right. Thank you for your answer.